# Load an sklearn model from different folder

Tags: python, python-3.x

So i'm trying to build an model with SKlearn. 
I've created the models and manually placed them into a folder. 
now I want to load the models (in a different `.py` file) from that specific folder.

my code to load the models looks like this.
the `a` variable is just to loop the different models.
it starts with 1 and ends with 4

```
filename = glob.glob('knn_model_folder/knn_model_' + str(a) + '.sav')
loaded_model = joblib.load(open(filename, 'rb'))
```

error I'm getting:

```
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not list
```

Comment: try `'knn_model_folder/knn_model_' + str(a) + '.sav'` without the `glob.glob`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`glob.glob()` will return a `list` of matching pathnames. You need only the pathname as a string for the `open` function:

```
filename = 'knn_model_folder/knn_model_' + str(a) + '.sav'
loaded_model = joblib.load(open(filename, 'rb'))
```

Comment: You can also see the documentation for `glob.glob()` [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html#glob.glob) if you're interested. Also please mark the answer as correct if it helped, thanks!